# Binding dependency property - set in custom user control, get in viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

The aim is to instantiate an object in a custom UserControl and then access that instance from a viewmodel. But the following is not working, the UpRatings property in the viewmodel is null.

#### Custom UserControl with Dependency Property

```
public partial class Scale:UserControl
{

    public Scale()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseRatingsProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MouseRatings",
        typeof(IObservable<double>),
        typeof(Scale));

    public IObservable<double> MouseRatings
    {
        get
        {
            return (IObservable<double>)GetValue(MouseRatingsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MouseRatingsProperty, value);                
        }
    }

    // requires System.Reactive NuGet
    private ISubject<double> _mouseRatings = new Subject<double>();

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);
        // _mouseRatings is the object instance I need to access in the viewmodel
        MouseRatings = _mouseRatings;
    }
}
```

#### View

```
<StackPanel>
    <scale:Scale MouseRatings="{Binding Path=UpRatings, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

#### ViewModel

```
// requires Prism.Wpf NuGet
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public IObservable<double> UpRatings { get; set; }

    // called after the DataContext is set, so the UpRatings binding should work here by now
    // see https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/60-Navigation.md
    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        // but UpRatings is unfortunately null here
        Trace.WriteLine(UpRatings == null ? "null" : "not null");
    }

}
```

Note that the DataContext is not set directly on the custom usercontrol but a parent of hers (and I can confirm that inside the custom usercontrol).

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using `RegisterAttached` to register a standard dependency property? Besides that, did you check that the `UpRatings` property in the view model is actually set, maybe after OnNavigatedTo?

Comment: @Clemens Well spotted! Changing RegisterAttached to the standard Register did not help. And I have tried to check UpRatings == null later as well e.g. 4 seconds after the usercontrol parent loads, but UpRatings is still null. Also, I just traced whether the MouseRatings get is called when I check UpRatings == null in OnNavigatedTo and it is!?

Comment: One more thing: `InitializeComponent()` should be called in the UserControl's constructor, not in the `OnInitialized()` override.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, fixed that too, but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started to work when MouseRatings = _mouseRatings; is called later as follows, while MouseRatings lost its value for some mysterious reason if setting it OnInitialized.

```
public Scale()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsVisibleChanged += Scale_IsVisibleChanged;
    }

private void Scale_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsVisible)
        {
            MouseRatings = _mouseRatings;
        }
    }
```

It would also work to set it in the UserControl Loaded event, but then the viewmodel has to wait extra time before being able to access the object.